# Support file globbing for extensions

Tags: c

For my school project, i am trying to implement file globbing for extensions like *.jpg, *.c. For that i have to use functions like readdir(2) and getdents(3) to read all files from current directory and then use strstr(3) to match them and then add them to list of args you pass to exec(2). i am not suppose to use glob (3). How should i implement this?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use `glob (3)`?

Comment: its for operating systems class, so efficiency is must and we are not suppose to use glob (3).

Comment: Good reason. It would be helpful to mention in the text that you are not supposed to use it, lest you get a bunch of answers suggesting it.

Comment: Are you expected to write your own regex code, or can you use provided regex functions?

Comment: Do you have to implement all the globbing features, like `[...]`, `?`, `{...}`? Or is it just a toy implementation that matches a filename with a know suffix, like your examples?

Answer (score 0):

POSIX provides functions to support globbing; standard C does not, and Microsoft does it all differently.

The header [`<fnmatch.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fnmatch.h.html) and the function [`fnmatch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fnmatch.html) could be part of the answer; this allows you to use the `opendir()`, `readdir()` and `closedir()` functions to scan a directory and match file names against your glob pattern.

If it weren't for the proscriptions in the question, you would probably find that the [`<glob.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/glob.h.html) header and the [`glob()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html) function are more appropriate.

You could look at the [`<wordexp.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/wordexp.h.html) header and [`wordexp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html).  This does even more work for you than `glob()` does, but if it wasn't proscribed, would save you a lot of effort.

Normally, `glob()` is the one that's most likely to do what you need.  However, since that's ruled out, maybe you can use `fnmatch()` which expects you to get the file names from ... well, actually, it doesn't care where you get the names from; it just validates whether the name you supply matches the file name pattern you specify.

If you're not meant to use any of these, then you will have to implement enough regex to match the shell globs that you're expected to recognize, and still use `readdir()` etc to check the available names.